# Creating dynamic getter methods in angular ,but getting error when accessed

Tags: angular, typescript, getter

creating getter methods in constructor by iterating over controls array

```
    constructor() {
                this.controls.forEach((control) => {
                  
                  Object.defineProperty(this, `${control}Control`, {
                    get: function () {
                      return this.salonRegister.get(control);
                    },
                  });
                });
                console.log(this);
              }
              controls = [
                'name',
              ];
            ngOnInit(): void {
                this.initForm();
              }
              initForm(): void {
                this.salonRegister = new FormGroup({
                  name: new FormControl(null, [
                    Validators.required,
                    Validators.maxLength(100),
                  ])
              }
            salonRegister: FormGroup;
        
        **template**
        
            <span *ngIf="!nameControl.valid && nameControl.touched">
                                            <span class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="nameControl.errors['required']">Salon name
                                                requ

ired</span>
                                    </span>
```

Error  ***Property 'nameControl' does not exist on type 'SalonListComponent'***

Comment: If nothing else, you should create form before you create these methods. But weird code to say the least.

Comment: Is it possible you format your code a bit better? It is a bit hard to read.

Comment: You get this error because your form does not exist when initializing your componenent.
Code in construct() will be executed before onInit(). In your code, the form does not yet exist when executing construct().
 I see two soloutions. 1) create the form before construct() (instead of in you onInit() ). 2) i do not recomend this - move your from creation to your construct() method, before looping over your array.

Comment: @BojanKogoj ,  user2403735 actually i am trying to set getter methods dynamically instead of manually writing each method for each controls in the form ,is there a better solution ?? also thanks for the response